# Is a Tor or cloudflare update the reason I suddenly getting cloudflared to death?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, circuit

All of a sudden almost every site, including this one cloudflares me, some I have to refresh the Tor circuit over 50 times to get it to work, and then it it dies within a few mins.

The thing is, this started very suddenly. Tor was great to browse on, then one day, I can hardly load a website.

It must mean maybe the latest browser bundle or cloudflare update, what else could be causing it. I sit there trying circuit after circuit. So frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Cloudfare update, they're blocking some Tor exit nodes for bot traffic or because the exit nodes are yelling, that they're exit nodes. Find a confident one =)